# How can I see music downloaded to my iPhone via Amazon Cloud Player in the Music app?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, music

I downloaded some songs to my iPhone using Amazon Cloud Player, but they are not showing up in the (official) Music app. I assume that Amazon Cloud Player downloaded MP3s to a directory on my device. How can I configure the Music app to look in this directory? I would prefer not to have to manually sync these songs via iTunes on my PC and then have two copies of these songs on my iPhone. Is there a way to import songs downloaded via Amazon Cloud Player into the Music app?

Specs:

- iPhone 4S
- iOS 6.1.3
- Amazon Cloud Player 2.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the iTunes app is currently able to add songs to the Music app on an iPhone/iPad. This leaves you with the following options

- Play the songs in the Amazon Cloud Player only
- Download them on your main computer and sync via iTunes. Maybe remove them from the Amazon Cloud Player to save storage space

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as you and have just found a way to do it.

1. Download ifunbox, its FREE software that views your iphone/ipod/ipodtouch etc. as though it was a hard drive so you can explore the directory of the device
2. Download any songs that you want from the cloud player service to your device
3. run ifunbox and go to the following (or similar) destination on the device "User device/User Applications/Cloud Player/Documents/CloudplayerDownloads"
4. Select the tracks that you want (they probably wont have readable titles but thats ok because when it copies them to the pc it should recognise the track names) and copy them to your pc by clicking "copy to pc"
5. Select where you want the files to go and save them.
6. Using itunes copy to the appropriate device. (you might have to convert the files to the right format, i havent got that far yet i wanted to tell you before i forgot, but i dont think so because they are mp3 when you download from amazon.

I have just done this with the new Black Sabbath album which i bought in vinyl, where are i am staying for the next few days has limited internet data but my phone has unlimited data so im going to use that instead

Hope this helps

Liam